# Microsoft Office Interop dll fails when application is deployed on server

Tags: interop, office-interop

I have used Excel and Powerpoint Interop Dlls in my web application, they run fine on local machine. However when I deploy it on IIS the application breaks giving following error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the follo
wing error: 80040154.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem rendering a PowerPoint to png in C# using COM under an IIS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780534/problem-rendering-a-powerpoint-to-png-in-c-sharp-using-com-under-an-iis-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of following things when dealing with applications using MS Office Interop Dlls delpoyed on server

1. Your application pool needs to run under a user account who has full permission to Interop Dlls
2. It would also be essential to intsall MS Office on your server

Comment: Jus figured out the permission issues for interop..Thanks a lot