# Retrieving the COM class factory for component issue in iis 10.0

Tags: iis-8

I have implemented export to PPT functionality in my report where i found some code to implement the same. For that i have added two dlls.
1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
2. Office.dll

And i have one Presenation.cs class where logic is written to take the image and export as PPT.

This i implemented in Visual studio and i am able to export the data in PPT format.
Now i published my application and hosted in my local iis.
When i tried to export the same in PPT then getting Com Class factory access denied.
[image: See image]

I did some googled and found it that need to provide some permission for specific file in DComConfig folder under my computer.
I tried to find the power point file but did not get it.
Then i given complete permission of IISUsers to My computer under properties.
But this workaround is not working.

One more workaround i found like i need to change specific application pool change identity from application pool to local system.
Then create desktop folder inside "**C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile**"

Then same need to do form SysWow64 folder as well.

This technique was working. But if we use application pool identity set to local system considering to security threat. We can't use local system.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem rendering a PowerPoint to png in C# using COM under an IIS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780534/problem-rendering-a-powerpoint-to-png-in-c-sharp-using-com-under-an-iis-service)

Comment: @LexLi, I have gone through the link and got to know using Aspose this problem can be solve. But when i googled found it that it is not free.Kindly suggest.